# How to set result of query as array with mongoose/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to set the result of a query as an array of an object being saved.

First I get the Items:

```
Item.find({...}, function...
```

which looks like that:

```
data =

[ { foo: [],
bar: true,
_id: 564f62b1659abdc22b9dd1da },
{ foo: [],
bar: true,
_id: 564f76b628bd4b62335bad7c } ]
```

Now I create an object which I want to save with the _ids of the query result as an "Item" ref array:

```
var itemholder = new Itemholder(req.body);
itemholder.items = ????
```

Itemholder has an array of "Item" refs called "items" which should look like this:

```
"items" : [ { "item" : ObjectId("564f62b1659abdc22b9dd1da"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("564f54c4e9bbbbee230647a4") },
    { "item" : ObjectId("564f76b628bd4b62335bad7c"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("564f67043f88a5b12d6c32ff") } ]
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's your question? Are you looking for how to convert your first set of results into the correct format for the second insert, or are you asking how to define the schema for the "Itemholder" model, or both, or something else?

Comment: I want to know how to convert the query result to a format i can set the "items" attribute/array with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it (probably not the best):

```
Item.find(..., function(err, data){
    if(err){
        ...
    }else{
        data = data.map(function(data) { return {'item': data._id}; });
        sprint.items = data;
        sprint.save(function(err2, data2){
        ...
```